# Moveit2 can't generate "small" trajectories

Tags: ros2, moveit

I have a problem where when I try to generate a small trajectory (under 1 mm of distance).

The planner I use (default OMPL with RRTConect) only generates 1 waypoint and thus my robot will not move.

Things I have tried so far:

1. Send the goal to the planner using moveit_msgs/tolerances with a tolerance way smaller than needed (it doesn't seem to work).
2. creating a custom trajectory and applying post-processing time parameterization (this didn't work due to some points having the exact same time and then the controllers rejecting this trajectory)
3. working with the custom trajectory without the post-processing time parameterization (this worked semi-well but clearly isn't the desired way to operate)

Is there any way to guarantee OMPL would generate more waypoints in a small trajectory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify that by setting this parameter in ompl_planning.yaml config file:

```
move_group:
  planner_configs:
    - RRTConnectkConfigDefault
  longest_valid_segment_fraction: 0.005
  default_planner_config: RRTConnectkConfigDefault
```

For example, in the case above the planner is set to generate waypoints every 5mm

Comment: Thank you for the comment.
for some reason, this change made the first move work but when I try to do some consecutive movements only the first one works.
I have tried to change the kinematics_solver_search_resolution in thought that might be related but it didn't help either

Comment: There are other parameters that you might need to change, like:
`"trajectory_execution.allowed_start_tolerance": 0.03,` or `ompl.path_tolerance`, `ompl.min_angle_change`, `ompl.start_state_max_bounds_error`....

Comment: thank you very much, this solved my problem.
Another question if you may as I see that you know your way around Moveit.
Those changes made a drastic change to the planning time(as expected).
Do you know a way to load those parameters at running time?

Comment: I think it's going to depend on how you are using MoveIt (i.e. in my case I use MoveIt Task Constructor instead of plain moveit). But, for example in this tutorial: https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/examples/motion_planning_api/motion_planning_api_tutorial.html#start you'll see that you have a variable called `planner_instance`, I guess you could make those changes directly on that variable?